# NVM , Node version manager is not working on Windows

Tags: node.js, nvm

I tried other questions as well but can't find specific answer. I'm trying to install `nvm` on Windows to use different node versions on different projects.

I installed `nvm`, but can't run `nvm install`. I am getting this terminal output:

```
nvm install v10.9.0
Clang v3.5+ detected! CC or CXX not specified, will use Clang as C/C++ compiler!
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.9.0/node-v10.9.0.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file /home/iClick
Warning: Digital/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.9.0/node-v10.9.0.tar.xz: No such
Warning: file or directory

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 846)
Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.9.0/node-v10.9.0.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/iClick Digital/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v10.9.0/node-v10.9.0.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows nvm is a diffrent one from the unix nvm. You may trying to download the wrong one. Download it [here](https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/24268127/f3defc70-9aa4-11e8-83e2-464480a185e4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20180903%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180903T162417Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=721eae175742fc22252c65c581e4666666af683947df575996d4b953c886fd01&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=19645544&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dnvm-setup.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream). Just extract and run the setup it should work fine. For different types of package formats follow this [link](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases).